# Minimizing AND gates in ANF

Tags: digital-logic

If I have a boolean expression made up of ANDs and XORs in algebraic normal form, are there any algorithms which can minimize the circuit further?

I'm looking to minimize AND gates specifically.

I'm building ANF from a truth table, so if there's a different way to go about getting a circuit made from XORs and ANDs starting with a truth table that has a minimal number of ANDs that'd be helpful too.

Thank you for any help you can provide!!

Edit: to be more explicit, I'm limited to using xor and and gates.

Comment: The only realistic answer is "maybe".

Comment: Karnot maps perhaps?  Also, the best way to make a complex table would be multiplexor.

Comment: ANF = what precisely?

Comment: Algebraic normal form.  https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_normal_form

Comment: XOR can be made to function like an inverter if you wire one input high. This means you can convert an AND gate to a NAND gate by putting an XOR inverter on the output. So solve for the NAND minimum solution using Karnough map. Then use one AND plus one XOR for each NAND gate.

Comment: why you are not posting boolean equation?

Comment: Because this is a general question. I am looking for a way to minimize and/xor based circuits in general, specifically looking to minimize ANDs.  I have an exotic computation setup and can only do XOR and AND, but AND is much slower/more resource intensive than XOR.  I need to be able to minimize arbitrary circuits.

Comment: This is for a research paper on the exotic type of computation I'm using and I need to make the circuits as lean as possible to get the best results. Possibly too much info, and might derail my question, but I'm currently converting functions to lookup tables, then converting the lookup tables to ANF. Now I want to minimize the number of ANDs in the ANF.

Answer (score 1):

There is an enormous amount of information about achieving minimal logic with only NAND or only NOR, both of which are functionally complete by themselves. The reason for this is that NAND and NOR can be made with a minimum number of transistors. I don't know if there is literature on minimum logic with AND and XOR. But you could use a minimum NAND solution to leverage this body of knowledge. A NAND gate for you would be an AND gate followed by an XOR based inverter. (XOR with one input wired high is an inverter). Initially I  was not planning to answer this question as it is not an area where I have deep knowledge, but nobody else provided a high quality answer, so I am giving it a shot.

Comment: Thanks mkeith.  My concern with using nand or anything else is that when I translate back to and/xor it won't be minimal anymore. However, you've given me info where I had non otherwise so thank you for that!

Comment: Yes, it is certainly not guaranteed to be minimal anymore. Maybe you can find some literature on minimal formulations with XOR and AND. Someone's thesis or something.

Answer (score 0):

Only optimisation will be possible through **Karnaugh map**. see link,

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karnaugh_map

Comment: Is it possible to use karnaugh maps with ANF which only has XOR and AND gates? I thought they could only work with OR and AND?

Comment: I updated my question but I'm limited to xor and and gates.